# How to avoid anemic data model? Can repositories be injected into entities?

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design

I have an immutable `User` entity:

```
public class User {
  final LocalDate lastPasswordChangeDate;
  // final id, name, email, etc.
}
```

I need to add a method that will return information if the user's password must be changed i.d. it has not been changed for more than the `passwordValidIntervalInDays` system setting.

The current approach:

```
public class UserPasswordService {
  private SettingsRepository settingsRepository;

  @Inject
  public UserPasswordService(SettingsRepository settingsRepository) {
    this.settingsRepository = settingsRepository;
  }

  public boolean passwordMustBeChanged(User user) {
    return user.lastPasswordChangeDate.plusDays(
        settingsRepository.get().passwordValidIntervalInDays
      ).isBefore(LocalDate.now());
  }
}
```

**The question is** how to make the above code more object oriented and avoid the anemic domain model antipattern? Should the `passwordMustBeChanged` method be moved to `User` if so how to access `SettingsRepository`, should it be injected into `User`'s constructor, or should a `Settings` instance be provided to the ctor, or should the `passwordMustBeChanged` method require a `Settings` instance to be provided?

The code of `Settings` and `SettingsRepository` is not important, but for completness, here it is:

```
public class Settings {
  int passwordValidIntervalInDays;
  public Settings(int passwordValidIntervalInDays) {
    this.passwordValidIntervalInDays = passwordValidIntervalInDays;
  }
}

public class SettingsRepository {
  public Settings get() {
    // load the settings from the persistent storage
    return new Settings(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694241/ddd-the-rule-that-entities-cant-access-repositories-directly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827670/is-it-ok-for-entities-to-access-repositories but none of them seem to answer my question

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://blog.inf.ed.ac.uk/sapm/2014/02/04/the-anaemic-domain-model-is-no-anti-pattern-its-a-solid-design/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a system-wide password expiration policy your approach is not that bad, as long as your `UserPasswordService` is a domain service, not an application service. Embedding the password expiration policy within User would be a violation of the SRP IMHO, which is not much better.

You could also consider something like (where the factory was initialized with the correct settings):

```
PasswordExpirationPolicy policy = passwordExpirationPolicyFactory().createDefault();
boolean mustChangePassword = user.passwordMustBeChanged(policy);


//class User
public boolean passwordMustBeChanged(PasswordExpirationPolicy policy) {
    return policy.hasExpired(currentDate, this.lastPasswordChangeDate);
}
```

If eventually the policy can be specified for individual users then you can simply store policy objects on `User`.

You could also make use of the ISP with you current design and implement a `PasswordExpirationPolicy` interface on your `UserPasswordService` service. That will give you the flexibility of refactoring into real policy objects later on without having to change how the `User` interacts with the policy.

If you had a `Password` value object you may also make things slightly more cohesive, by having something like (the password creation date would be embedded in the password VO):

```
//class User
public boolean passwordMustBeChanged(PasswordExpirationPolicy policy) {
    return this.password.hasExpired(policy);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have chosen the "your approach is not that bad" solution :)

Comment: @AdamSiemion For a more OOP design just implement a PasswordExpirationPolicy interface on your service and then you can do `user.passwordMustBeChanged(yourDomainService)`. You will have less friction if your design changes eventually and it's really not a huge refactor.

Comment: Create explicit predicate-like VALUE OBJECTS for specialized purposes. A SPECIFICATION is
a predicate that determines if an object does or does not satisfy some criteria.

Comment: @wangyiran That's pretty much what the `PasswordExpirationPolicy` is in my answer, no?

Comment: @plalx yes,i just refer the Eric Evans book reference

Answer (score 1):

just to throw out another possible solution would be to implement a long-running process that could do the expiration check and send a command to a PasswordExpiredHandler that could mark the user with having an expired password.

Comment: I just wanted to add that it's not an option that is mutually exclusive with what we proposed. Even with a long-running process, you need a clean way to check the policy.

Comment: @plax agreed. what's nice about the long-running process is you could bake other types of things within the workflow, like sending out a friendly reminder when their password is about to expire.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon a document that provides an answer to my question:

> A common problem in applying DDD is when an entity requires access to data in a repository or other gateway in order to carry out a business operation. One solution is to inject repository dependencies directly into the entity, however this is often frowned upon. One reason for this is because it requires the plain-old-(C#, Java, etc…) objects implementing entities to be part of an application dependency graph. Another reason is that is makes reasoning about the behavior of entities more difficult since the Single-Responsibility Principle is violated. A better solution is to have an application service retrieve the information required by an entity, effectively setting up the execution environment, and provide it to the entity.

http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/