# What should I put in infrastructure layer according to DDD

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I just want to clearlify one thing. As I understand, infrastructure layer should contain things related to external modules or system only (IO, DB, Gateways...). But while exploring examples over the internet of DDD implementation I noticed that there are many examples when people put different things in this layer, such as random number generation, helpers, generic things and so on...\

E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820247/9254020) Roy Oliver suggested such structure, where you can find things as `Project.Infrastructure.Components`. Could someone explain me is it acceptable or it's just a missunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I put in infrastructure layer according to DDD?

DDD doesn't advocate any particular arrangement of source code, nor packaging.

What that really means is that your "best practices" for those questions are expected to be answered elsewhere.

You may want to look into [package by feature](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205).